# Calling two functions in one link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to JS and don't know how to deal with this issue. I have a link with `onClick` function which calls two functions. Unfortunately, unlike the first function, the second one (`live_update();`) isn't working when the link is clicked. I am sure the function `live_update()` is working fine but what is the right format to call two functions inside `onClick`? Here is the link I have:

```
<a class="float-left mt-1 mr-1" onclick="fetchInfo('profiles.php?act=q_sale&u_key={u_key}&rcoup=1','sale_coupon');live_update(this);">Link</a>
```

Comment: I can't read your full answer. It is shorten by stackoverflow. What can I do?

Comment: both functions fire at the same time. live_update have nothing to update when it fires. Change your logic and create a promise on the first function. When it is resolved fire the second one. This must be the logic inside your click handler.

Comment: Can you please share your live_update() function as well?

Comment: "the second one isn't working when the link is clicked" — The syntax you have there will work (even if it is 1990s style code) to call two functions in sequence so either (a) `live_update` doesn't work at all or (b) `fetchInfo` threw an exception so the code never reaches the next statement or (c) `fetchInfo` is asynchronous and `live_update` depends on its result. You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why don't you just declare one function which calls the 2 functions you need. Also your fetchInfo function is likely to be asynchronous, so the 2nd function will likely fire before the fetch has completed. Please read ["Master the javascript interview whats a promise"](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261#:%7E:text=A%20promise%20may%20be%20in,the%20promise%20constructor%20is%20invoked.) for how promises work.

I don't know the details of your fetchInfo function or the live_update, but assuming the fetchInfo (returns a promise/ is asynchronous) and assuming live_update takes the data that fetchInfo returns as a parameter then you could do something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<script>

function handleClick() {

fetchInfo('profiles.php?act=q_sale&u_key={u_key}&rcoup=1','sale_coupon')
    .then( function (data) {
        live_update(data)
    })


}

</script>

<button onclick="handleClick()">The time is?</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

If you read the article I posted above then you will realize that the `then` function will only fire once the fetchInfo promise has been `fulfilled`.

What is probably happening is that your `live_update` function is being invoked before the `fetch_info` function has completed. That's how asynchonous functions work.